# Execute a SoapClient __soapCall without WSDL page

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm working with a SOAP API, and they've disabled the WSDL document that's normally located in the base .asmx URL for SOAP APIs. The page is instead a 404 page when viewed without an XML request. Right now, simply instantiating a SoapClient fails (`$soap = new SoapClient($url);`, the error is `Premature end of data in tag html line 1`). I'm assuming here that a new instance of SoapClient tries to retrieve the WSDL from the server. Is there a way of turning this off? Of saying 'I want to use SoapClient, but don't do any calls until I tell you the XML call that you'll be using (along with all required data)'?

EDIT: I've tried setting `cache_wsdl` to `WSDL_CACHE_NONE` but I still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run SoapClient in non-wsdl mode therefore you must set the wsdl parameter of the SoapClient c'tor to null

```
public SoapClient::SoapClient ( mixed $wsdl [, array $options ] )
```

Initialize it the following way

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => http://your_domain/your_webservice",
                                     'uri'      => "http://namespace_of_the_webservice/"));

location...The location of the webservice
uri...The namespace of the target webservice
```